# How to read the state of WIFI/BLUETOOTH on or off on pressing home button or if we close the application

Tags: android, bluetooth, wifi

I have an application where I am enabling and disaling the wifi and bluetooth and the  problem is on pressing home button both WIFI/BLUETOOTH  are getting off

On pressing home button  or if we close the application, if wifi/bluetooth are ON they should be in ON state and viceversa

Comment: your problem is not clear.can u explain it more..?

Comment: if we close the application bluetooth/wifi should not get off  if they are on

Comment: you have onuserleavehint() method in activity which will called when user press Home Key so override this method

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how can we check whether bluetooth/wifi is on or off, how to check , could u plz share some piece of code

Answer (score 0):

You can check wifi/bluetooth is enabled or not as:

**For WIFI:**

```
WifiManager wifiManager = (WifiManager) this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);  
  if(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){  
    // Wifi is not enable
  }else{  
    // Wifi is  enable
  }
```

manifest.xml permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.UPDATE_DEVICE_STATS"></uses-permission>  
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"></uses-permission>
```

**For Bluetooth** :

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
    // Device does not support Bluetooth
} else {
    if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
        // Bluetooth is not enable
    }
    else
    {
     // Bluetooth is  enable
    }
}
```

manifest permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

For Handleing Home and Back key You should place your code in the [onPause()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onPause%28%29) method to ensure it's used whenever the app gets backgrounded.

and you can also override `onKeyDown` for handling Home and Back Key as:

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HOME) {
        Log.i("TESTE", "HOME KEY PRESSED");
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);    
}
```

Comment: can we read the status of wifi/bluetooth in onecreate() I mean when we start the application it works as we need

Comment: yes you will read status of wifi/bluetooth in oncreate of your Activity or Service.

Comment: Thanks, could u plz tell how to do that,  as I am new to android I didnt get the proper Idea